# Reading from UART port

Tags: c, driver, linux-device-driver, uart

I'm writing a simple UART driver in linux for ARM926EJ-S. Inside the read function of the driver. If enter key (carriage return) was pressed, I want it to return the no. of bytes read till that point.

```
uart_data = (unsigned char)ioread8((void*)UART_DR(uart0_addr));
printk(KERN_ERR " %d ",(unsigned int)uart_data ); //prints 13 when pressing enter key
if ((unsigned char)13 == uart_data) //if carriage return 
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Carriage Return\n");
    goto out;
}
```

When I press enter key on the UART terminal, it receives it as a carriage return, but the control flow never gets inside the if block. Please help.

Comment: Nice. Why do you print "Line feed" when you're receiving a "Carriage Return"?

Comment: ^^^^ Linux programmer; they don't understand CR :)

Comment: 'control flow never gets inside the if block' - does the printk() return?  If you break on the 'if', is it hit?

Comment: My bad! It was for debugging purpose anyway!!

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, printk() returns and the code following this above blockworks fine!

Comment: Well, if you break on the 'if', inspect uart_data and it's still 13, I have to say that I'm just as stuck as you are.  All I can suggest is that you stop on the if and trace through the generated assembler, instruction-by-instruction, to find out why the thing fails:(

Comment: Umm.. printk() might be a bit greedy - how much interrupt stack have you allocated?

Comment: Could be something *very* trivial - Printk uses a ring buffer in the kernel. If reading the UART register triggers a lot of other printk messages (Maybe, because the FIFO now allows further reading, whatever), the ring buffer might run-around and drop your message for the benefit of others. You could try and increase that buffer by re-compiling the kernel. Your code looks pretty much O.K to me.

Comment: And you are not telling us whether you have proof you can receive *any character at all* - Can you elaborate on that? Otherwise something else might be wrong. The UART data register is actually a 16-bit register. Not sure if it is valid on your hardware to read only the lower half.

Comment: Following this code, I use copy_to_user() to copy the value in 'uart_data' to a user-space buffer and the user process always receives correct data when it reads from this buffer. So I'm sure the printk() isn't causing any stack corruption. And besides, I also tried commenting out printk() and ran it, but still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: And not just for carriage return, even when I use 'a' as a delimiter, as in `if('a' == uart_data)` , it still doesn't get inside the if block though I entered 'a' in uart terminal.